# What's the 2017th derivative of $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x^2}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I started solving the first few derivatives to see if I can find a pattern but I can't find it.

I tried to do something with general Leibniz rule but I don't really know if it's correct.
$f'(x)=\frac{2x}{(1-x^2)^2}=2xf(x)^2$

$f^{(n)}(x)=[\text{Leibniz}]=2x(f(x)^2)^{(n-1)} + 2(n-1)(f(x)^2)^{(n-2)}$

Is this correct? What can I do next or is there another way of solving it?

Comment: Use $\dfrac{1}{1-x^2}=\dfrac12(\dfrac{1}{1-x}+\dfrac{1}{1+x})$ and find $n$-th derivation for each term.

Comment: While there are elementary ways to tackle this specific problem, a general approach to finding the derivative with respect to $x$ of the composite function $f(g(x))$ is given by the [Faa di Bruno Formua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faà_di_Bruno%27s_formula).  That approach is overkill here, but it is a useful-to-know approach.